# Using R Studio to pull phrases from a CSV

Tags: r, csv, data-mining, text-analysis

Using R I would like to take a single CSV and pull out the most common two and three word phrases.  I've been searching Google and Stackoverflow and could not find a simple way to do this.

I know how to read a CSV into R but I have not found out how to extract the data into the appropriate datatype and perform operations on to get what I am looking for.

Requirements:

1. Remove all non alpha numeric text from the CSV
2. Replace words using a synonym list
3. Remove words with no meaning (at, the, etc)
4. Get a count of the common phrases for both two word phrases and three word phrases
5. Make all text lowercase

Also, what data types are best suited for this type of analysis?  dataframe?  tm? corpus?  etc?

```
My_SRs <- read.csv("C:/example_folder/username/Documents/my_data.csv")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've actually figured out how to do this in Python using the Natural Language Toolkit module, but I know that R is more powerful in this type of analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The `tm` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf) will do what you are looking for.

From the manual, to load a file:

```
txt <- system.file("my_data.csv", control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE)))
```

Create a `corpus`:

```
Corpus(DirSource(txt)
```

From there, you can use `TermDocumentMatrix` or go a different route with `PlainTextDocument` and `termFreq` to deliver word frequencies.

Comment: I am sorry to have to ask this, but I have not been able to get system.file to read my CSV.  I've tried moving the file to default directory, I've tried making it an absolute path.  But I'm not able to load the file using system.file as you have in your example above.  Is there another library I need to require other than tm?

Comment: txt <- system.file("C:/Users/username/folder/folder/my_data.csv",
                   control = list(
                     removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                  removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                  tolower = TRUE,
                                  stopwords = TRUE))

tail(txt)